# C# const protected vs internal

Tags: c#, .net, constants, protected, internals

Why is "internal const" being overridden in a child class but "protected const" can't?

Sample code:

```
    class A
    {
        internal const string iStr = "baseI";
        protected const string pStr = "baseP";

        void foo()
        {
            string s = B.iStr; //childI
            string t = B.pStr; //baseP
        }
    }

    class B : A
    {
        internal new const string iStr = "childI";
        protected new const string pStr = "childP";
    }
```

Expected B.pStr to return "childP".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Protected members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/protected) can only be accessed within the same class as they are declared, or in derived classes of the class in which they are declared.

Therefore, the protected `pStr` declared in `B`, with the value "childP", cannot be accessed in the parent class `A`.

Note that you are not "overriding" anything, which usually involves the `override` keyword. You are simply declaring two new members in `B`, *in addition to* those that `B` inherits from `A`. In total, `B` has the following constants:

```
internal const string iStr = "baseI";
protected const string pStr = "baseP";
internal new const string iStr = "childI";
protected new const string pStr = "childP";
```

Accessible members that are declared in `B` are preferred over inherited members with the same name. In other words, the members declared in `B` *hides* the ones declared in `A` (and does so explicitly with [`new`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier)). Therefore, when you do `B.iStr`, you get "childI". When you do `B.pStr` however, you can only access the inherited member.

Answer (score 1):

Since the new const `B.pStr` is protected, it is visible in `B` and classes derived from `B` only. So, it is invisible in class `A`.

Note that the `new` keyword in this context **hides** inherited members. Constants are static and cannot be overridden.